# Different Environment of Anaconda Prompt and Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have always been executing my python script through a drag and drop approach to the anaconda prompt as the script is executed in the anaconda environment. I have this script in which it should be executed on another pc through a drag and drop approach in that pc's anaconda prompt. Turns out a certain library wasn't able to be imported. I tried running the script on jupyter notebook in that PC and it works. This would be the first time that I feel that anaconda prompt and jupyter notebook aren't running in the same environment.

Any help would greatly be appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you start you anaconda prompt, if you don't change your enviornment, it will be default in 'base' environment.
And I don't know where your run your jupyternotebook, but you may double check which anaconda environment it is running with.

PS: Since i am still not able to comment. I will write the reply here, hope it helps you a bit.

Comment: Hey, no worries, thanks so much for the attempt. I will definitely try to investigate this. Thanks so much for the contribution!